# php superglobal function ($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization']) in never set. why?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, authorization, token, superglobals

[image]I have php function that is supposed to verify if there is a token, and if so, search my table for a company  name that matches. The function works fine when I use xampp in localhost. When I do it in prod on the server, it gives me a 'token undefined' error, What could possibly be causing the error?
my php function

```
    public function findCompany(){
        echo "global var= ";
//        var_dump($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization']);
//        var_dump($GLOBALS);
        var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (isset($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization'])) {
            if ($id = $this->VerifyUserToken($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $data = [
            'company_name' => $_POST['company_name']
        ];

        $companies = $this->currentModel->findCompany($data);

        if($companies){
            echo json_encode($companies);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['success' => false]);
        }
    }
            else {
                echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => "invalid token"]);
            }

        } else {
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => "token undefined"]);

        }

    }
}
```

the verifyUserToken function

```
public function verifyUserToken($token, $ip) {
        $db = new Database();

        $db->query('SELECT * FROM auth WHERE token = :token AND expiry >now()');

        $db->bind(':token', $token);
        //check database if token exists and is not expired
        if($res = $db->single()) {
            // checks if token matches to ip address
            // returns user or contact id if verified else returns false
            if($res->token === $token && $res->ip === $ip) {
                $this->cleanTokens();
                if($res->user_id >0) {
                    return $res->user_id;
                }
//              
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I checked the database, and the token is clearly there. anyway, it's not giving me an invalid token message. it looks like the token isn't being sent.
It works fine when I do it in localhost on my machine.

IN order to debug, I used var_dump to see what gets sent. I don't have much experience with PHP, but it looks like my headers authorizations never gets set. what could be the solution

see the images and code below for what I get in the console when I try. I truncated some of the paths for security purposes

```
        echo "global var= ";
and
        var_dump($GLOBALS);
you get
   ["GLOBALS"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["headers"]=>
    array(13) {
      ["Host"]=>
      string(20) "globalplantbased.com"
      ["Connection"]=>
      string(10) "keep-alive"
      ["Content-Length"]=>
      string(2) "15"
      ["Pragma"]=>
      string(8) "no-cache"
      ["Cache-Control"]=>
      string(8) "no-cache"
      ["Accept"]=>
      string(33) "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      ["User-Agent"]=>
      string(115) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
      ["Content-Type"]=>
      string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ["Origin"]=>
      string(27) "http://globalplantbased.com"
      ["Referer"]=>
      string(59) "http://globalplantbased.com"
      ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
      string(13) "gzip, deflate"
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.9"
      ["Cookie"]=>
      string(31) "_ga=GA1.2.1321601484.1609694939"
```

or
echo "global var= ";
and
var_dump($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization']);

or
echo "global var= ";
and
var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

[![($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization'])[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXAkN.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXAkN.png)
[image: ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])]

Comment: You don't show anywhere where and how `$GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization']` gets set...

Comment: it's in the findCompany function. I checked what happens locally and it does actually have the the token in headers authorization. I'm posting a picture (at beginning of post) which shows what' sin my console when I doecho "global var= ";
        var_dump($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization']);. it does actually have the token in the header. It seems like it's being removed on the server. why is it happening what can I do about it.

Comment: no it’s not......

Answer (score -1):

$this->VerifyUserToken($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization...

Has to be

$this->verifyUserToken($GLOBALS['headers']['Authorization

Windows does not make a Difference between capital and small Letters

Regards,

Henrik

Comment: nice catch @ Henrik. but I still get token undefined. but it was giving me warnings which I now got rid of

Comment: findcompany seems to be to late, did you look at the request headers of the http call if the Authorization header is set? If yes it gets lost before calling findcompany and if not you have to change the http call

Comment: it's not setting the header. why? how would I change the http call?

Comment: PHP functions and methods are NOT case sensitive regardless of the OS.